# What is the time complexity of this Lowest Common Ancestor algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, big-o

I just wrote this, but I think it's a rather slow implementation. I'm not interested in someone providing a faster algorithm; I want to know the time complexity of *this* algorithm (and why).

```
   class Solution {
        public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
            if (root == null) {
                return null;
            }   

            boolean leftContainsP = contains(root.left, p); 
            boolean leftContainsQ = contains(root.left, q);

            if (leftContainsP && leftContainsQ) {
                return lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
            }

            boolean rightContainsP = contains(root.right, p); 
            boolean rightContainsQ = contains(root.right, q);

            if (rightContainsP && rightContainsQ) {
                return lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);
            }   

            return root;
        }

        public boolean contains(TreeNode root, TreeNode node) {
            if (root == null) {
                return false;
            } 

            if (root == node) {
                return true;
            }

            return contains(root.left, node) || contains(root.right, node);
        }  
    }
```

Here's my thought:

For each iteration of lowestCommonAncestor, I call "contains" 4 times. Contains runs in O(p), where p is the number of nodes in the tree.

But, I always call contains on a tree half the size of the input.

In addition, the lowestCommonAncestor function recurses logN times (since it always calls on a child).

Thus, my complexity is:

(N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 ... ) * 4

= O(N)

But I don't think it's actually that fast, intuitively, since it's repeating a lot of work.

Comment: what is `N` here?

Comment: `But I don't think it's actually that fast` - O(N) does not mean `fast` it means - time is growing linearly, nothing more

Comment: actually its O(N) only if it is perfectly balanced tree, where depth = logN, in general - worst case is O(N^2)

Comment: Your analysis assumes the tree is balanced... and is also incorrect even if the tree is balanced.   You should write out the recurrence relation.